# Flow, type destructured object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, flowtype

I'm having trouble figuring out syntax to type this kind of destructured object

```
const { height: deviceHeight, width: deviceWidth } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

Right now `deviceHeight` and `deviceWidth` are uncovered, both should be numbers.

Comment: Should that say undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
const { height: deviceHeight, width: deviceWidth }: { height: number, width: number } = Dimensions.get("window");
```

You can see that this correctly types `deviceHeight` and `deviceWidth` by plugging it into something like this:

```
// @flow
const { height: deviceHeight, width: deviceWidth }: { height: number, width: number } = { height: 1, width: 2 };

function logString(str: string) {
  console.log(str);
}

logString(deviceHeight);
```

...which gives this output:

```
logString(deviceHeight);
          ^ Cannot call `logString` with `deviceHeight` bound to `str` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2].
```

([See it on flow.org](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBjWA7AzgF1Ab1ABYCmAlgOYFYBcoAJkQG4nJEASpFWANKPCbVgI16TFgHV+g0AF8a+YuUo00AVwC2AIyIAnHnwFDQqzTpmgAvHkIcloAIx7JhgEwyA3IkSQVaZFhLooHBkAMpY2iRoZAAU2No0cZFkAJR4iKCgqJiw0EQAdMGx4cke0p7BYRFR0SLMbDZYJUA))

Comment: That did the trick, mad syntax though, I would've never guessed. Thank you